# Explicit solution, find x(t), y(t)

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have a nonlinear system of equations:

$$\dot{x}=x(y-1)$$
$$\dot{y}=y^{2}(x-1)$$

And I wish to find x(t) and y(t) of this system. I might be missing a trick, but I just can't see to get it to work. The $xy$ and $y^{2}x$ are throwing me off. I am aware there are two equilibrium points at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Any hints or what method to use are appreciated.

Comment: Non-linear equations like this usually don't have (useful) analytical solutions. If you need $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ I would solve it numerically. Even the simplest integrator (Euler's method) should work fine here atleast for starting values that are not too far away from $(0,0)$. Fix $x_1 = x(0)$ and $y_1 = y(0)$ and set $\Delta t = \frac{t_{\rm max}}{n}$ where $n$ is the number of steps between $t=0$ and $t=t_{\rm max}$ (should be large) and then iterate and compute $x_{i+1} = x_i + \Delta t \cdot x_i (y_i - 1)$ and $y_{i+1} = y_i + \Delta t\cdot y_i^2(x_i - 1)$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think you can get explicit solutions for $x$ and $y$ as a function of $t$. But you can get the equations of the trajectories in the phase plane. From the equations we get
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2(x-1)}{x(y-1)}\implies\frac{y-1}{y^2}\,dy=\frac{x-1}{x}\,dx.
$$
Integrating
$$
\log y+\frac1y=x-\log x+C,
$$
or
$$
x\,y\,e^{1/y-x}=C.
$$

Answer (score 0):

One direct approach -- from the second equation you have
$$
x = 1 + y'y^{-2}
$$
thus
$$
x' = y''y^{-2} -2 y'y^{-3}
$$
and you can now plug this into the first equation and solve for $y$ in a 1-variable ODE...

Important to keep in mind this assumes $y \ne 0$...

Comment: How do you suggest to solve $$yy''-(y^2-y+2)y'+y^3(1-y)=0\ ?$$